# C# OOP Print Result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I'm new to the c# in visual studio, I'm trying to use OOP that prints the result
I want to print the result as:

> Hello. I am a cocker spaniel. Woof! I'm (**Big or Small**), the Colour is
> white, and I have 4 legs.

Since the value I set is 10 so it will always be small...

Here is my code:

```
public Dog()
        {
            barkSound = "Woof!";
            breed = "cocker spaniel";
            dogHeight = 10;
            dogColour = "white";
            noOfLEgs = 4;
        }

  public string GetSpeech()
    {
        dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm " 
                    + dogHeight + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs +" legs" ;
        return dogSpeech;
    }
    
    private bool IsBig(int dogHeight)
    {
        if (dogHeight < 50)
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Should I modify the "IsBig" Method or another better way to print the result as expected?
Wish that I could stick with boolean.

Comment: `IsBig` is not a class. It is a method.

Comment: @S.Akbari opps... thanks edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

You can either rename `IsBig` to `GetSizeDescription` and return a string:

```
private string GetSizeDescription() {
    if (dogHeight < 50)
    {
        return "Small";
    } else
    {
        return "Big";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public string GetSpeech()
{
    dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm " 
                + GetSizeDescription() + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs +" legs" ;
    return dogSpeech;
}
```

or, you can keep the `IsBig` method unchanged, and change the `GetSpeech` method to this:

```
public string GetSpeech()
{
    dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm " 
                + (IsBig() ? "Big" : "Small") + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs +" legs" ;
    return dogSpeech;
}
```

Comment: may i ask another question?

Comment: If i want to input a new value from textbox to my instance... how could i do it?

Comment: @JakeCube I really want to help you, but without any code, I can't. You should post that as a different question using the "Ask Question" button. Remember to show your code and research efforts!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202976/c-sharp-using-textbox-to-change-instance-value-and-display

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the method

```
private string GetSizeString(int dogHeight)
{
    if (dogHeight < 50)
    {
        return "Small";
    }
    return "Big";
}
```

And then simply

```
public string GetSpeech()
{
    return "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm " 
                + GetSizeString(dogHeight) + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs +" legs" ;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to stick with bool?

Comment: then you can change GetSpeech:  ... + (IsBig() ? "Big" : "Small") + " ...

Comment: If i want to input a new value from textbox to my instance... how could i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the IsBig Method. Maybe you should make this a property but that's not too important. You could make a new method:

```
private string GetSizeText(bool isBig)
{
   if (isBig)
     return "Big";

   return "Small";
}
```

Then your GetSpeech looks like:

```
  public string GetSpeech()
    {
        dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm " 
                    + GetSizeText(IsBig(dogHeight)) + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs +" legs" ;
        return dogSpeech;
    }
```

This is the easy solution. You could also create an enum with Big and Small as values and print this enum values with `ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your full code.

```
public class Dog
{

    public Dog()
    {
        barkSound = "Woof!";
        breed = "cocker spaniel";
        dogHeight = 10;
        dogColour = "white";
        noOfLEgs = 4;
    }

    public string barkSound { get; private set; }
    public string breed { get; private set; }
    public string dogColour { get; private set; }
    public int dogHeight { get; private set; }
    public int noOfLEgs { get; private set; }

    public string GetSpeech()
    {

        string dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + " I'm "
                    + (IsBig(dogHeight) ? "Big" : "Small") + ", Colour is " + dogColour + ", I have " + noOfLEgs + " legs";
        return dogSpeech;
    }

    private bool IsBig(int dogHeight)
    {
        if (dogHeight < 50)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Calling should be like this.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
string speech = dog.GetSpeech();
```

Replace `dogHeight`  with `(IsBig(dogHeight) ? "Big" : "Small")` thats it.