# Textbox to change instance value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I'm trying to set new variable into my Filed (instance) value into new value through text box... but I've no idea how to make it.. here is my code wish I can get some insight from someone else.

[image]

```
private string barkSound;
private string breed;
private int dogHeight;
private string dogColour;
private static int noOfLegs;
```

All the get and set has been set.

```
public Dog()   
{
    barkSound = "Woof!";
    breed = "cocker spaniel";
    dogHeight = 10;
    dogColour = "white";   
}

public string GetSpeech()
{
    dogSpeech = "Hello. I am a " + breed + ". " + barkSound + "\n I'm " 
                    + (IsBig()? "Big" : "Small") +", i got " + DogHeight +" CM, Colour is " + dogColour + ". I have " + noOfLegs + " Legs" ;
    return dogSpeech;
}

public Dog()
{
    barkSound = "Woof!";
    breed = "cocker spaniel";
    // Question(C) add Constructor for dogHeight. dogColour and breed.
    dogHeight = 10;
    dogColour = "white";
}
```

Comment: If I understand, you want to create new `Dog` object with properties, entered into your textboxes?

Comment: if i entered a new barksound "MEOW" at textbox, it will replace the "Woof" to meow. Once i print into my list box my bark value will become "meow"

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I have created an form like you, At the Create button I created new `Dog`.

Here is my `Dog` class,

```
public class Dog
        {
            private string barkSound;
            private string breed;
            private int dogHeight;
            private string dogColour;
            public Dog(string bark, string breed, int height, string color)
            {
                this.barkSound = bark;
                this.breed = breed;
                this.dogHeight = height;
                this.dogColour = color;

            }
            public string BarkingSound { get { return this.barkSound; } }
            public string BreedName { get { return this.breed; } }
            public string Height { get { return this.dogHeight.ToString(); } }
        }
```

Here is the Create button's click (And I have `Dog` list to add Dogs to it);

```
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
private void createBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dog myDog = new Dog(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox3.Text), textBox4.Text);
            dogs.Add(myDog);
        }
```

At GetDogs Button's `Click` I loop over all dogs and add them into `listbox`.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in dogs)
            {
                string text = "Hello. I am a " + item.BreedName + ". " + item.BarkingSound + "etc";
                listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }
```

The question is not clear, maybe you want to change the existing value of the dog.

So first we need to make change at `Dog` class.

```
public class Dog{
        private string barkSound;
        private string breed;
        private int dogHeight;
        private string dogColour;
        public Dog(string bark, string breed, int height, string color)
        {
            this.barkSound = bark;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.dogHeight = height;
            this.dogColour = color;

        }
        public string BarkingSound { get { return this.barkSound; }  set { this.barkSound = value; }  } // so we can set variables like this dog.BarkingSound = "bla"
        public string BreedName { get { return this.breed; } }
        public string Height { get { return this.dogHeight.ToString(); } }
    }
```

Why did we do that ?

At `listbox's selected index change event`, first we need to find the `Dog` inside our list by using `ElementAt()`. Then Check textbox of BarkSound, if it is not empty set it to existing Dog's `BarkingSound`,

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Dog TempDog = dogs.ElementAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                TempDog.BarkingSound = textBox1.Text;
            }

        }
```

Tried to explain with both way, Hope that one of them will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your fields have `private` modifier. This means, that another code outside `Dog` class can't modify your fields. Also I recommend to use auto-generated properties:

```
SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

So, if you want to modify fields, properties or methods everywhere outside your class, you should declare them with `public` modifier. In your case:

```
public string BarkSound;
public string Breed;
public int DogHeight;
public string DogColour;
public static int NoOfLegs;
```

After you have created a `Dog` object (`Dog dog = new Dog();`), you can change your properties like this:

```
dog.BarkSound = barkSoundTextBox.Text;
```